# QRelationalTable category with relation

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I have small problem in Qt. I have two tables, one with `products`, one with `categories`. I want to display list of products in `QTableView`. No big deal. It's also not big deal to assign relation and display name of category instead of id in one column.

But, in `categories` I have an internal relation, so I can make subcategories. It's done very simple by creating additional column with `parentId`.

And here is the problem... How can I display that relation in `QTableView`? I mean instead of displaying only name of category that products belong to, it will display all parent categories also, for example that way:

Have 3 categories:

- Food (with no parent)
- Fruits (with parent Food)
- Citrus(with parent Fruits)

Product:

- Orange assigned to category Citrus.

In `TableView` in column `Category` it should be:

> Food/Fruits/Citrus

or

> Food->Fruits->Citrus

or something like that...

How to do it? Subclass `QRelationalTableModel` and make additional relation? Or make Delegate for that column? Or maybe both?

Comment: What RDMS are you using? Also, your implementaion of a heirachy may be an efficiency trap - this is the "default" method, there are better ways.

Comment: Currently I'm using only SQLite, in future I'm planning expanding this app for using MySQL also.

What are better ways of doing it? And why You call it "better"?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back?src=embed. The bit you need starts at slide 48.

Comment: Ok, I can change my db, not big deal. I think the solution with closure table will be best for me. But still i have problem: how to implement it in my app using Qt sql model?

Comment: There I cannot help you, I have no knowledge of Qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arleady did it...

What I've done:
For table `categories`

```
CREATE TABLE categories (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100), parent NUMERIC)
```

created table `categories_closure` (all SQL statements are for SQLite) :

```
CREATE TABLE categories_closure (parent NUMERIC, child NUMERIC, depth NUMERIC)
```

next, created some triggers to automate my closure table

```
CREATE TRIGGER categories_delete AFTER DELETE ON categories
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM categories_closure WHERE child=OLD.id;
    UPDATE categories SET parent=OLD.parent WHERE parent=OLD.id;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER categories_insert AFTER INSERT ON categories
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO categories_closure (parent, child, depth) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.id, 0);
    INSERT INTO categories_closure (parent, child, depth)
        SELECT p.parent, c.child, p.depth+c.depth+1
            FROM categories_closure p, categories_closure c
            WHERE p.child=NEW.parent AND c.parent=NEW.id;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER categories_update AFTER UPDATE OF id,parent ON categories
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM categories_closure WHERE child=OLD.id;
    INSERT INTO categories_closure (parent, child, depth) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.id, 0);
    INSERT INTO categories_closure (parent, child, depth)
        SELECT p.parent, c.child, p.depth+c.depth+1
        FROM categories_closure p, categories_closure c
        WHERE p.child=NEW.parent AND c.parent=NEW.id;
    UPDATE categories SET parent=NEW.id WHERE parent=OLD.id;
END;
```

Now I can get string of all parent categories with simple query, co I created an View

```
CREATE VIEW categories_resolved AS
SELECT
    id,
    group_concat(name, ' ') AS fullname,
    group_concat(parent) AS branch
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.id,
        cc.parent,
        c2.name
    FROM categories c
    LEFT JOIN categories_closure cc ON c.id=cc.child
    LEFT JOIN categories c2 ON c2.id=cc.parent
    ORDER BY cc.depth DESC
)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

And finally I used this View on relation in `QSqlRelationalTableModel` instead of `categories` table. Simple, and no need for creating model, view, proxy, delegate or modify code of Qt classes.